# Javascript submit button not working in VueJS table

Tags: javascript, vue.js

How to trigger the submit button when the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key is pressed on the keyboard. The <kbd>Enter</kbd> key works perfectly fine from the first textbox to the last textbox.

When I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> in the last textbox, the focus goes to the submit button. However, my problem is that the submit button does not work when using the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

In contrast, the submit button works perfectly fine with a mouse click. I would like to be able to submit using the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key as well.

**main.js**

```
key: {
    enter: function (self, focusable, e) {
      if (e.which === 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
  
        // Find the index of the current element in the focusable list
        const currentIndex = focusable.index(self);
  
        // Calculate the index of the next element to focus
        let nextIndex = currentIndex + 1;
  
        // If it's the last element in the row, focus on the submit button
        if (nextIndex >= focusable.length) {
          const submitButton = $("button[type='submit']");
          if (submitButton.length > 0) {
            submitButton.focus(); // Trigger the click event on the    submit button
            return false; // Prevent further processing
          }
        }
  
        // Focus on the next element and select its content if applicable
        focusable.eq(nextIndex).focus().select();
  
        // If the focused element is a checkbox, toggle its state
        if (focusable.eq(nextIndex).is(":checkbox")) {
          focusable.eq(nextIndex).prop("checked", function(i, value) {
            return !value;
          });
        }
  
        return false;
      }
    },
},
```

**template** (submit button)

```
<v-container
  v-if="init && init.permissionToEdit"
  fluid
  class="ma-0 pa-0 mt-3 d-flex flex-column align-center"
>
  <v-btn
    x-small
    @click="onSubmitEditClick"
  >
    Submit
  </v-btn>
</v-container>
```

I've tried changing the focus, but the output remains the same.

[image]

[image]

Comment: it's probably because you `if (e.which === 13) {
        e.preventDefault();` perhaps you should check which element had focus before blindly preventing the default action

Comment: Why use the jQuery library with Vue.js? Don't. They are completely different with distinct development philosophies.

Answer (score 1):

#### Reflection

I don't really understand why you're using jQuery with Vue.js. At least, that's the impression I got from your code. The two systems don't align well. jQuery continuously performs DOM validations, which conflicts with Vue.js, as Vue.js does not detect DOM changes in a completely native Vue.js application.

#### Solution

The task can be perfectly accomplished with Vue.js and native JavaScript. If I understand correctly, you want to pass the focus on <kbd>Enter</kbd> key press through the input fields, and after the last input field, you want to trigger the click event of the submit button. I have implemented this.

When <kbd>Enter</kbd> is pressed (using the `@keydown.enter.prevent` event on the `<input>`), the `focusNextField` function is called. Based on a logic, it either gives focus to the next input field or triggers the click event of the submit button.

I dynamically rendered the input fields with a loop to demonstrate that the example works with dynamically generated input fields.

In the `focusNextField` function, I simply retrieve the active element and use the array of input fields declared in the reactive DOM reference `myFormElement`.

I tried to comment on each step.

#### Example

```js
const { createApp, ref, reactive, computed } = Vue;

const app = createApp({
  setup() {
    const myFormElement = ref(null)
    const formData = ref({
      email: '',
      username: '',
      password: '',
    });
    
    // Remove focus from the active element
    const removeFocus = () => {
      const activeElement = document.activeElement;
      if (activeElement && activeElement.tagName === 'INPUT') {
        activeElement.blur();
      }
    };

    // Add focus to next field
    const focusNextField = (event) => {
      // Prevent the default HTML Form submit click event on Enter, allowing it to occur only when we explicitly want it to happen (see the submitForm function called in the logic)
      event.preventDefault();
      
      if (event.key === 'Enter') {
        const activeElement = document.activeElement;
        const formInputs = Array.from(myFormElement.value.getElementsByTagName('input'));

        if (activeElement && formInputs.includes(activeElement)) {
          const currentIndex = formInputs.indexOf(activeElement);
          
          // Check if this is the last input field. If yes, then the button follows, assuming all input fields have been correctly filled
          const isLastInput = currentIndex === formInputs.length - 1;
          if (isLastInput === true) {
            // In the if branch, we call the submitForm, which returns a false value in case of incorrect validation. In this case, the return void function stop inside the if branch does not execute; instead, the code proceeds to the "otherwise..." comment
            if (success = submitForm()) {
              return; // End function here
            }
            
            // Otherwise, this function continues
            console.log("Something error (just example if validated will false)");
          }
          
          // Focus to next input
          const nextIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % formInputs.length;
          formInputs[nextIndex].focus();
        }
      }
    };

    const submitForm = () => {
      // Here goes your validation
      const validated = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) === 1; // Random true or false
      
      // If the validation is incorrect, I stop the function and return with a false value
      if (validated === false) {
        return false;
      }
      
      // Otherwise, this function continues
      
      // There is no longer a need for the focuses, so we clear the focus from the active element
      removeFocus();
      
      // Submission logic for the form
      console.log('Form submitted:', formData.value);
      // You can add your form submission logic here
      
      return true;
    };

    return {
      myFormElement,
      formData,
      focusNextField,
      submitForm,
    };
  }
}).mount('#app');
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.3.4/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <form ref="myFormElement">
    <!-- Form content -->
    <input
      v-for="key of Object.keys(formData)"
      type="text"
      v-model="formData[key]"
      :placeholder="key"
      @keydown.enter.prevent="focusNextField"
      required
    />

    <!-- Submit button -->
    <button @click="submitForm">
      Submit
    </button>
  </form>
</div>
```

#### More information

- [How to reference a DOM element in Vue.js? --> Template Refs](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs)
   (Vue Docs)
- [How can I get the currently focused element?
  --> `documnet.activeElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/activeElement) (MDN Docs)
- [How can the original event be prevented from occurring? --> `event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) (MDN Docs)
- [How can I determine which key press triggered the event? --> `event.key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key#examples) (MDN Docs)

Comment: I'll try this to implement in my code sir thanks . I hope this solve my problem i need to use javascript it is required in my tasks.

Comment: I have attached a working example code. If you encounter any issues, please let me know. If you understood the logic behind my answer, I trust you gained some useful new knowledge!